# How can I gradient fill svg text shrunk by a constraining textLength value without javascript and consistency across browsers?

Tags: html, css, svg, cross-browser, gradient

What I want on my site is a single line of gradient filled text. I want to be able to modify the text, adding and removing characters, without worry about how it will fit or align on a single line. Even if someone's device fails to load the font I design the text with, the overall width of the text should not change, which the [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/textLength) promise I can do with `textLength`:

> By using textLength, you can ensure that your SVG text displays at the same width regardless of conditions including web fonts failing to load (or not having loaded yet).

Rather than show you my whole site, I threw together [a toy site](https://bl.ocks.org/jspinoza3/raw/e55fb41492ae7c440b575b690e6d7dad/)  to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish. Here's a screenshot of it rendering properly in desktop chrome.

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Below is the [code](https://gist.github.com/jspinoza3/e55fb41492ae7c440b575b690e6d7dad):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

 
 svg{
     width:800px;
     height:960px;
     background-color:#cccccc;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>


<svg  viewBox="0 0 100 120"> 
    <linearGradient 
        id="grad" 
        x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="100%" 
        gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
    >
        <stop stop-color="cyan" offset="15%"/>
        <stop stop-color="blue" offset="40%"/>
        <stop stop-color="magenta" offset="65%"/>
        <stop stop-color="red" offset="80%"/>
    </linearGradient>
  
    <text   
        textLength="100" 
        lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs"
        font-size="20"
        x="0" 
        y="20"
        fill="url(#grad)"
    >
        This line will shrink if "textLength" is set to a small enough value 
    </text> 
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

In my `<text>` tag I use `textLength="100"` and the viewbox is also set to width 100: `viewBox="0 0 100 120"`, which is why everything fits neat and tidy on one line even though I crammed way to many characters in there.

It all fails when I go to the toy site on my iphone, however, as you can see in this  screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Chrome, safari, firefox- it doesn't matter, they all fail and look the same. What was once around 80 characters of text, appears to be clipped down to 13 characters. The weird thing is, the clipping appears to occur in the middle of the SVG viewbox, while the visible letters appear to be scrunching/compressing properly, as though the textLength property is doing it's job.

I did some pretty extensive testing, and ended up throwing together this [other](https://spinoza.je/svgwoes/) not-so-toy site that compares various combinations of the `textLength` and `fill` attributes` to come to the conclusion that the only time things get messed up is when gradient fill and textLength are used in combination, as the result of browser specific mis-rendering with no documented explanation.

Is there anyway I can change my code above to make my toy site render properly or will I have to resort to JavaScript and wait on other browsers to get on the ball?

Comment: On IOS Chrome and Firefox are merely shells on top of Webkit. That's why it's all the same because it's not Chrome's or Firefox's rendering engine that's being used it's Apple's webkit. Raise a webkit bug.

Comment: Thanks. [bug raised](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=219293).